# Ptolemy's table of chords

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity, trigonometry

Ptolemy's *Almagest* contains a [table of chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords) that effectively served as the world's only comprehensive trigonometric table for over a millennium. In modern form it looks like this:

\begin{array}{|l|rrr|rrr|}
\hline
{}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \tfrac12 &  0 & 31 & 25 & 1 & 2 & 50 \\
{}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 1 & 1 & 2 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 50 \\
{}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 1\tfrac12 & 1 & 34 & 15 & 1 & 2 & 50 \\
{}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
109 & 97 & 41 & 38 & 0 & 36 & 23 \\
109\tfrac12 & 97 & 59 & 49 & 0 & 36 & 9 \\
110 & 98 & 17 & 54 & 0 & 35 & 56 \\
110\tfrac12 & 98 & 35 & 52 & 0 & 35 & 42\\
111 & 98 & 53 & 43 & 0 & 35 & 29 \\
111\tfrac12 & 99 & 11 & 27 & 0 & 35 & 15 \\
112 & 99 & 29 & 5 & 0 & 35 & 1\\
112\tfrac12 & 99 & 46 & 35 & 0 & 34 & 48 \\
113 & 100 & 3 & 59 & 0 & 34 & 34 \\
{}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
179 & 119 & 59 & 44 & 0 & 0 & 25 \\
179\frac12 & 119 & 59 & 56 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
180 & 120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}

The table has 360 lines, each in the following format:

- An angle \$\theta\$ in degrees, ranging from ½° to 180° inclusive in ½° increments.
- The chord length subtended by \$\theta\$ in a circle of radius 60. This length is equal to \$c(\theta)=120\sin\frac\theta2\$ and is given as three numbers: the integer part comes first and the first and second sexagesimal (base 60) digits follow.
- A "sixtieths" column used for linear interpolation, giving \$\frac{c(\theta+1/2^\circ)-c(\theta)}{30}\$. This follows a similar format to the chords column but lists three sexagesimal digits; the integer part is always 0 and has been omitted in the table above for brevity (it was written out in the original). Also note that 0 appears in this column at 180° instead of a negative value as the formula would imply.

### Task

Output all 360 lines of the table, each containing seven numbers – without the zero integer parts of the sixtieths column – as described above:

```
0.5 [0, 31, 25] [1, 2, 50]
1.0 [1, 2, 50] [1, 2, 50]
1.5 [1, 34, 15] [1, 2, 49]
2.0 [2, 5, 39] [1, 2, 49]
2.5 [2, 37, 4] [1, 2, 49]
3.0 [3, 8, 28] [1, 2, 48]
3.5 [3, 39, 53] [1, 2, 48]
4.0 [4, 11, 17] [1, 2, 47]
4.5 [4, 42, 40] [1, 2, 47]
5.0 [5, 14, 4] [1, 2, 46]
5.5 [5, 45, 27] [1, 2, 45]
6.0 [6, 16, 49] [1, 2, 44]
6.5 [6, 48, 11] [1, 2, 43]
7.0 [7, 19, 33] [1, 2, 42]
7.5 [7, 50, 54] [1, 2, 41]
8.0 [8, 22, 15] [1, 2, 40]
8.5 [8, 53, 35] [1, 2, 39]
9.0 [9, 24, 54] [1, 2, 38]
9.5 [9, 56, 13] [1, 2, 36]
10.0 [10, 27, 31] [1, 2, 35]
10.5 [10, 58, 49] [1, 2, 33]
11.0 [11, 30, 5] [1, 2, 32]
11.5 [12, 1, 21] [1, 2, 30]
12.0 [12, 32, 36] [1, 2, 28]
12.5 [13, 3, 50] [1, 2, 27]
13.0 [13, 35, 4] [1, 2, 25]
13.5 [14, 6, 16] [1, 2, 23]
14.0 [14, 37, 28] [1, 2, 21]
14.5 [15, 8, 38] [1, 2, 19]
15.0 [15, 39, 47] [1, 2, 17]
15.5 [16, 10, 56] [1, 2, 14]
16.0 [16, 42, 3] [1, 2, 12]
16.5 [17, 13, 9] [1, 2, 10]
17.0 [17, 44, 14] [1, 2, 7]
17.5 [18, 15, 17] [1, 2, 5]
18.0 [18, 46, 20] [1, 2, 2]
18.5 [19, 17, 21] [1, 2, 0]
19.0 [19, 48, 21] [1, 1, 57]
19.5 [20, 19, 19] [1, 1, 54]
20.0 [20, 50, 16] [1, 1, 51]
20.5 [21, 21, 12] [1, 1, 48]
21.0 [21, 52, 6] [1, 1, 45]
21.5 [22, 22, 58] [1, 1, 42]
22.0 [22, 53, 49] [1, 1, 39]
22.5 [23, 24, 39] [1, 1, 36]
23.0 [23, 55, 27] [1, 1, 33]
23.5 [24, 26, 13] [1, 1, 29]
24.0 [24, 56, 58] [1, 1, 26]
24.5 [25, 27, 41] [1, 1, 22]
25.0 [25, 58, 22] [1, 1, 19]
25.5 [26, 29, 1] [1, 1, 15]
26.0 [26, 59, 39] [1, 1, 11]
26.5 [27, 30, 15] [1, 1, 8]
27.0 [28, 0, 48] [1, 1, 4]
27.5 [28, 31, 20] [1, 1, 0]
28.0 [29, 1, 50] [1, 0, 56]
28.5 [29, 32, 18] [1, 0, 52]
29.0 [30, 2, 44] [1, 0, 48]
29.5 [30, 33, 8] [1, 0, 44]
30.0 [31, 3, 30] [1, 0, 39]
30.5 [31, 33, 49] [1, 0, 35]
31.0 [32, 4, 7] [1, 0, 31]
31.5 [32, 34, 22] [1, 0, 26]
32.0 [33, 4, 35] [1, 0, 22]
32.5 [33, 34, 46] [1, 0, 17]
33.0 [34, 4, 55] [1, 0, 12]
33.5 [34, 35, 1] [1, 0, 8]
34.0 [35, 5, 5] [1, 0, 3]
34.5 [35, 35, 6] [0, 59, 58]
35.0 [36, 5, 5] [0, 59, 53]
35.5 [36, 35, 1] [0, 59, 48]
36.0 [37, 4, 55] [0, 59, 43]
36.5 [37, 34, 47] [0, 59, 38]
37.0 [38, 4, 36] [0, 59, 32]
37.5 [38, 34, 22] [0, 59, 27]
38.0 [39, 4, 5] [0, 59, 22]
38.5 [39, 33, 46] [0, 59, 16]
39.0 [40, 3, 25] [0, 59, 11]
39.5 [40, 33, 0] [0, 59, 5]
40.0 [41, 2, 33] [0, 59, 0]
40.5 [41, 32, 3] [0, 58, 54]
41.0 [42, 1, 30] [0, 58, 48]
41.5 [42, 30, 54] [0, 58, 42]
42.0 [43, 0, 15] [0, 58, 37]
42.5 [43, 29, 33] [0, 58, 31]
43.0 [43, 58, 49] [0, 58, 25]
43.5 [44, 28, 1] [0, 58, 18]
44.0 [44, 57, 10] [0, 58, 12]
44.5 [45, 26, 16] [0, 58, 6]
45.0 [45, 55, 19] [0, 58, 0]
45.5 [46, 24, 19] [0, 57, 53]
46.0 [46, 53, 16] [0, 57, 47]
46.5 [47, 22, 9] [0, 57, 41]
47.0 [47, 51, 0] [0, 57, 34]
47.5 [48, 19, 47] [0, 57, 27]
48.0 [48, 48, 30] [0, 57, 21]
48.5 [49, 17, 11] [0, 57, 14]
49.0 [49, 45, 47] [0, 57, 7]
49.5 [50, 14, 21] [0, 57, 0]
50.0 [50, 42, 51] [0, 56, 53]
50.5 [51, 11, 18] [0, 56, 46]
51.0 [51, 39, 41] [0, 56, 39]
51.5 [52, 8, 0] [0, 56, 32]
52.0 [52, 36, 16] [0, 56, 25]
52.5 [53, 4, 29] [0, 56, 17]
53.0 [53, 32, 37] [0, 56, 10]
53.5 [54, 0, 43] [0, 56, 3]
54.0 [54, 28, 44] [0, 55, 55]
54.5 [54, 56, 42] [0, 55, 48]
55.0 [55, 24, 35] [0, 55, 40]
55.5 [55, 52, 25] [0, 55, 32]
56.0 [56, 20, 12] [0, 55, 25]
56.5 [56, 47, 54] [0, 55, 17]
57.0 [57, 15, 33] [0, 55, 9]
57.5 [57, 43, 7] [0, 55, 1]
58.0 [58, 10, 38] [0, 54, 53]
58.5 [58, 38, 4] [0, 54, 45]
59.0 [59, 5, 27] [0, 54, 37]
59.5 [59, 32, 46] [0, 54, 29]
60.0 [60, 0, 0] [0, 54, 21]
60.5 [60, 27, 10] [0, 54, 12]
61.0 [60, 54, 17] [0, 54, 4]
61.5 [61, 21, 19] [0, 53, 56]
62.0 [61, 48, 16] [0, 53, 47]
62.5 [62, 15, 10] [0, 53, 39]
63.0 [62, 41, 59] [0, 53, 30]
63.5 [63, 8, 44] [0, 53, 21]
64.0 [63, 35, 25] [0, 53, 13]
64.5 [64, 2, 1] [0, 53, 4]
65.0 [64, 28, 33] [0, 52, 55]
65.5 [64, 55, 1] [0, 52, 46]
66.0 [65, 21, 24] [0, 52, 37]
66.5 [65, 47, 43] [0, 52, 28]
67.0 [66, 13, 57] [0, 52, 19]
67.5 [66, 40, 6] [0, 52, 10]
68.0 [67, 6, 11] [0, 52, 1]
68.5 [67, 32, 12] [0, 51, 52]
69.0 [67, 58, 7] [0, 51, 42]
69.5 [68, 23, 59] [0, 51, 33]
70.0 [68, 49, 45] [0, 51, 23]
70.5 [69, 15, 27] [0, 51, 14]
71.0 [69, 41, 4] [0, 51, 4]
71.5 [70, 6, 36] [0, 50, 55]
72.0 [70, 32, 3] [0, 50, 45]
72.5 [70, 57, 26] [0, 50, 35]
73.0 [71, 22, 43] [0, 50, 26]
73.5 [71, 47, 56] [0, 50, 16]
74.0 [72, 13, 4] [0, 50, 6]
74.5 [72, 38, 7] [0, 49, 56]
75.0 [73, 3, 5] [0, 49, 46]
75.5 [73, 27, 58] [0, 49, 36]
76.0 [73, 52, 46] [0, 49, 26]
76.5 [74, 17, 29] [0, 49, 15]
77.0 [74, 42, 6] [0, 49, 5]
77.5 [75, 6, 39] [0, 48, 55]
78.0 [75, 31, 6] [0, 48, 45]
78.5 [75, 55, 29] [0, 48, 34]
79.0 [76, 19, 46] [0, 48, 24]
79.5 [76, 43, 58] [0, 48, 13]
80.0 [77, 8, 4] [0, 48, 3]
80.5 [77, 32, 6] [0, 47, 52]
81.0 [77, 56, 2] [0, 47, 41]
81.5 [78, 19, 52] [0, 47, 31]
82.0 [78, 43, 38] [0, 47, 20]
82.5 [79, 7, 17] [0, 47, 9]
83.0 [79, 30, 52] [0, 46, 58]
83.5 [79, 54, 21] [0, 46, 47]
84.0 [80, 17, 44] [0, 46, 36]
84.5 [80, 41, 2] [0, 46, 25]
85.0 [81, 4, 15] [0, 46, 14]
85.5 [81, 27, 22] [0, 46, 3]
86.0 [81, 50, 23] [0, 45, 52]
86.5 [82, 13, 19] [0, 45, 40]
87.0 [82, 36, 9] [0, 45, 29]
87.5 [82, 58, 54] [0, 45, 18]
88.0 [83, 21, 32] [0, 45, 6]
88.5 [83, 44, 5] [0, 44, 55]
89.0 [84, 6, 33] [0, 44, 43]
89.5 [84, 28, 54] [0, 44, 32]
90.0 [84, 51, 10] [0, 44, 20]
90.5 [85, 13, 20] [0, 44, 8]
91.0 [85, 35, 24] [0, 43, 56]
91.5 [85, 57, 22] [0, 43, 45]
92.0 [86, 19, 15] [0, 43, 33]
92.5 [86, 41, 1] [0, 43, 21]
93.0 [87, 2, 42] [0, 43, 9]
93.5 [87, 24, 16] [0, 42, 57]
94.0 [87, 45, 45] [0, 42, 45]
94.5 [88, 7, 7] [0, 42, 33]
95.0 [88, 28, 24] [0, 42, 21]
95.5 [88, 49, 34] [0, 42, 9]
96.0 [89, 10, 39] [0, 41, 56]
96.5 [89, 31, 37] [0, 41, 44]
97.0 [89, 52, 29] [0, 41, 32]
97.5 [90, 13, 15] [0, 41, 19]
98.0 [90, 33, 55] [0, 41, 7]
98.5 [90, 54, 28] [0, 40, 55]
99.0 [91, 14, 55] [0, 40, 42]
99.5 [91, 35, 16] [0, 40, 30]
100.0 [91, 55, 31] [0, 40, 17]
100.5 [92, 15, 40] [0, 40, 4]
101.0 [92, 35, 42] [0, 39, 52]
101.5 [92, 55, 38] [0, 39, 39]
102.0 [93, 15, 27] [0, 39, 26]
102.5 [93, 35, 10] [0, 39, 13]
103.0 [93, 54, 47] [0, 39, 0]
103.5 [94, 14, 17] [0, 38, 47]
104.0 [94, 33, 41] [0, 38, 35]
104.5 [94, 52, 58] [0, 38, 21]
105.0 [95, 12, 9] [0, 38, 8]
105.5 [95, 31, 13] [0, 37, 55]
106.0 [95, 50, 11] [0, 37, 42]
106.5 [96, 9, 2] [0, 37, 29]
107.0 [96, 27, 46] [0, 37, 16]
107.5 [96, 46, 24] [0, 37, 3]
108.0 [97, 4, 55] [0, 36, 49]
108.5 [97, 23, 20] [0, 36, 36]
109.0 [97, 41, 38] [0, 36, 22]
109.5 [97, 59, 49] [0, 36, 9]
110.0 [98, 17, 54] [0, 35, 56]
110.5 [98, 35, 51] [0, 35, 42]
111.0 [98, 53, 43] [0, 35, 29]
111.5 [99, 11, 27] [0, 35, 15]
112.0 [99, 29, 4] [0, 35, 1]
112.5 [99, 46, 35] [0, 34, 48]
113.0 [100, 3, 59] [0, 34, 34]
113.5 [100, 21, 16] [0, 34, 20]
114.0 [100, 38, 26] [0, 34, 6]
114.5 [100, 55, 29] [0, 33, 53]
115.0 [101, 12, 25] [0, 33, 39]
115.5 [101, 29, 14] [0, 33, 25]
116.0 [101, 45, 57] [0, 33, 11]
116.5 [102, 2, 32] [0, 32, 57]
117.0 [102, 19, 1] [0, 32, 43]
117.5 [102, 35, 22] [0, 32, 29]
118.0 [102, 51, 36] [0, 32, 15]
118.5 [103, 7, 44] [0, 32, 0]
119.0 [103, 23, 44] [0, 31, 46]
119.5 [103, 39, 37] [0, 31, 32]
120.0 [103, 55, 23] [0, 31, 18]
120.5 [104, 11, 2] [0, 31, 4]
121.0 [104, 26, 34] [0, 30, 49]
121.5 [104, 41, 58] [0, 30, 35]
122.0 [104, 57, 16] [0, 30, 20]
122.5 [105, 12, 26] [0, 30, 6]
123.0 [105, 27, 29] [0, 29, 52]
123.5 [105, 42, 25] [0, 29, 37]
124.0 [105, 57, 13] [0, 29, 23]
124.5 [106, 11, 55] [0, 29, 8]
125.0 [106, 26, 29] [0, 28, 53]
125.5 [106, 40, 55] [0, 28, 39]
126.0 [106, 55, 15] [0, 28, 24]
126.5 [107, 9, 27] [0, 28, 9]
127.0 [107, 23, 32] [0, 27, 55]
127.5 [107, 37, 29] [0, 27, 40]
128.0 [107, 51, 19] [0, 27, 25]
128.5 [108, 5, 2] [0, 27, 10]
129.0 [108, 18, 37] [0, 26, 56]
129.5 [108, 32, 5] [0, 26, 41]
130.0 [108, 45, 25] [0, 26, 26]
130.5 [108, 58, 38] [0, 26, 11]
131.0 [109, 11, 43] [0, 25, 56]
131.5 [109, 24, 41] [0, 25, 41]
132.0 [109, 37, 32] [0, 25, 26]
132.5 [109, 50, 15] [0, 25, 11]
133.0 [110, 2, 50] [0, 24, 56]
133.5 [110, 15, 18] [0, 24, 41]
134.0 [110, 27, 38] [0, 24, 25]
134.5 [110, 39, 51] [0, 24, 10]
135.0 [110, 51, 56] [0, 23, 55]
135.5 [111, 3, 53] [0, 23, 40]
136.0 [111, 15, 43] [0, 23, 25]
136.5 [111, 27, 26] [0, 23, 9]
137.0 [111, 39, 0] [0, 22, 54]
137.5 [111, 50, 27] [0, 22, 39]
138.0 [112, 1, 47] [0, 22, 23]
138.5 [112, 12, 58] [0, 22, 8]
139.0 [112, 24, 2] [0, 21, 53]
139.5 [112, 34, 59] [0, 21, 37]
140.0 [112, 45, 47] [0, 21, 22]
140.5 [112, 56, 28] [0, 21, 6]
141.0 [113, 7, 1] [0, 20, 51]
141.5 [113, 17, 26] [0, 20, 35]
142.0 [113, 27, 44] [0, 20, 20]
142.5 [113, 37, 54] [0, 20, 4]
143.0 [113, 47, 56] [0, 19, 48]
143.5 [113, 57, 50] [0, 19, 33]
144.0 [114, 7, 36] [0, 19, 17]
144.5 [114, 17, 15] [0, 19, 1]
145.0 [114, 26, 46] [0, 18, 46]
145.5 [114, 36, 9] [0, 18, 30]
146.0 [114, 45, 24] [0, 18, 14]
146.5 [114, 54, 31] [0, 17, 59]
147.0 [115, 3, 30] [0, 17, 43]
147.5 [115, 12, 22] [0, 17, 27]
148.0 [115, 21, 5] [0, 17, 11]
148.5 [115, 29, 41] [0, 16, 55]
149.0 [115, 38, 8] [0, 16, 40]
149.5 [115, 46, 28] [0, 16, 24]
150.0 [115, 54, 40] [0, 16, 8]
150.5 [116, 2, 44] [0, 15, 52]
151.0 [116, 10, 40] [0, 15, 36]
151.5 [116, 18, 28] [0, 15, 20]
152.0 [116, 26, 8] [0, 15, 4]
152.5 [116, 33, 40] [0, 14, 48]
153.0 [116, 41, 4] [0, 14, 32]
153.5 [116, 48, 20] [0, 14, 16]
154.0 [116, 55, 28] [0, 14, 0]
154.5 [117, 2, 28] [0, 13, 44]
155.0 [117, 9, 20] [0, 13, 28]
155.5 [117, 16, 4] [0, 13, 12]
156.0 [117, 22, 40] [0, 12, 56]
156.5 [117, 29, 8] [0, 12, 40]
157.0 [117, 35, 27] [0, 12, 24]
157.5 [117, 41, 39] [0, 12, 7]
158.0 [117, 47, 43] [0, 11, 51]
158.5 [117, 53, 39] [0, 11, 35]
159.0 [117, 59, 26] [0, 11, 19]
159.5 [118, 5, 6] [0, 11, 3]
160.0 [118, 10, 37] [0, 10, 47]
160.5 [118, 16, 0] [0, 10, 30]
161.0 [118, 21, 15] [0, 10, 14]
161.5 [118, 26, 22] [0, 9, 58]
162.0 [118, 31, 21] [0, 9, 42]
162.5 [118, 36, 12] [0, 9, 25]
163.0 [118, 40, 55] [0, 9, 9]
163.5 [118, 45, 29] [0, 8, 53]
164.0 [118, 49, 56] [0, 8, 37]
164.5 [118, 54, 14] [0, 8, 20]
165.0 [118, 58, 24] [0, 8, 4]
165.5 [119, 2, 26] [0, 7, 48]
166.0 [119, 6, 20] [0, 7, 31]
166.5 [119, 10, 6] [0, 7, 15]
167.0 [119, 13, 43] [0, 6, 59]
167.5 [119, 17, 12] [0, 6, 42]
168.0 [119, 20, 33] [0, 6, 26]
168.5 [119, 23, 46] [0, 6, 10]
169.0 [119, 26, 51] [0, 5, 53]
169.5 [119, 29, 48] [0, 5, 37]
170.0 [119, 32, 36] [0, 5, 20]
170.5 [119, 35, 16] [0, 5, 4]
171.0 [119, 37, 48] [0, 4, 48]
171.5 [119, 40, 12] [0, 4, 31]
172.0 [119, 42, 28] [0, 4, 15]
172.5 [119, 44, 35] [0, 3, 58]
173.0 [119, 46, 34] [0, 3, 42]
173.5 [119, 48, 25] [0, 3, 26]
174.0 [119, 50, 8] [0, 3, 9]
174.5 [119, 51, 43] [0, 2, 53]
175.0 [119, 53, 9] [0, 2, 36]
175.5 [119, 54, 27] [0, 2, 20]
176.0 [119, 55, 37] [0, 2, 3]
176.5 [119, 56, 39] [0, 1, 47]
177.0 [119, 57, 32] [0, 1, 30]
177.5 [119, 58, 17] [0, 1, 14]
178.0 [119, 58, 54] [0, 0, 58]
178.5 [119, 59, 23] [0, 0, 41]
179.0 [119, 59, 44] [0, 0, 25]
179.5 [119, 59, 56] [0, 0, 8]
180.0 [120, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0]
```

The separation between lines and between numbers in a line must be clear, but is otherwise unrestricted. **Rounding in the last sexagesimal place should be to the nearest integer** – this makes the table to be output here not exactly correspond with Ptolemy's original, i.e. the table should match the *code block* above.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Very interesting question! I have translated Ptolemy’s Almagest to French and created a website, almageste.ca, featuring my translation. I would have loved to have (yet upcoming) answers to this question to lighten my code!

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>71</s> 78 bytes

+7 fix a bug noted by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257712/ptolemys-table-of-chords/257717?noredirect=1#comment569572_257717)

```
#/2|Ramp[DMSList/@Round[{c@#,2c[1+#]-2c@#},60^-2]]&~Array~360
c=120Sin[#/4°]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Zl@19Z36gmKDG3INrFN9gns7hE3yEovzQvJbo62UFZxyg52lBbOVbXCMip1TEziNM1io1Vq3MsKkqsrDM2M@BKtjU0MgjOzItW1jc5tCFW7X9AUWYe0Iy0/wA)

Yields a list of rows expressed as `θ | {{chord...}, {sixtieths...}}`.

`DMSList` conveniently converts a number into its integer part and two sexagesimal places. We can multiply the sixtieths by 60 to extract its three parts using the same function.

Comment: Oh my, `DMSList` is a [chef's kiss] find. And even better, this ancient sexagesimal system (Babylonian in origin I believe) is ultimately why our clocks have 60 seconds/minute and 60 minutes/hour anyway—so the function is actually completely on topic!

Comment: @GregMartin Sexagesimal originated with the Sumerians.

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 126 bytes

```javascript
for(v=10/573,a=1,F=q=>[q*60|0,(q=q*216e3+.5|0)/60%60|0,q>0?q%60:a=0];a;)print(a/2,F(v/2),F(-v+(v=4*Math.sin(++a/229.183118))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLDsIgFAW/xoRX4QIW0Ya6684vMC5ujI11UUtLWPXfkXg2M8kk54MZt@c6LanJvpTxu5IcNKj2ZAUGLYYQQ3@PzMEOgsQQmdHuZblsd6DKweEfYg/XWPWCAR4ddnRZpzkRVEYMJCtDK5rM6/WR3TC95TbNhPPazVlqb7X2tK6UHw)

Or [try this version with a custom print](https://tio.run/##VY5BDoIwEEWv0oXGFurQFkXUFHfsPAEhcaKoGEMtkMZEPTtWXfk38/NeMjMXdNjt2/rWT1063Nq66YkmFACQEZ2RvWk6c63gak50N3pgIUroTV7fqwOV7EWKD5MlXEzd0AknE/Yqf1D9wx0bjqalTksRzRcxRy15rq3OChsk4ik4tdoGSiZVHML8KViUiPFX2ExsrK8r1KJc45p9v6QYKZ5TFynmx9SFfvUs2GJ/hs5fDUPv1RJkGkuZMp9heAM) for easier comparison with the table provided in the challenge.

#### Commented

```javascript
for(                 // loop:
  v = 10 / 573,      //   good enough approximation of 4 * sin(pi / 720)
  a = 1,             //   angle in half degrees
  F = q =>           //   helper function taking a value q in [0,2]
    [                //   and returning a triplet consisting of:
      q * 60 | 0,    //   - the integer part of q * 60
      ( q =          //   - the first sexagesimal place, obtained by
          q * 216e3  //     updating q to floor(q * 60 ** 3 + 0.5),
          + .5 | 0   //
      ) / 60 % 60    //     dividing by 60, reducing modulo 60
      | 0,           //     and rounding towards 0
      q > 0 ? q % 60 //   - the 2nd sexagesimal place, which is
            : a = 0  //     max(q mod 60, 0) (the max() is needed for
    ];               //     the last line of the table)
  a;                 //   stop when a = 0
)                    //
print(               // print:
  a / 2,             //   the angle in degrees
  F(v / 2),          //   followed by the 1st triplet, using v / 2
  F(                 //   followed by the 2nd triplet:
    -v +             //     subtract the current value of v and add
    ( v =            //     the new value of v defined as:
      4 * Math.sin(  //       4 times the sine of:
        ++a /        //         increment a and divide it by a good
        229.183118   //         enough approximation of 720 / pi
      )              //
    )                //
  )                  //   end of 2nd call to F
)                    // end of print()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 54 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

A full program printing the table

```apl
d,0 60 60∘⊤¨⌊.5+↑c,¨2×0,⍨¯2-/c←432e3×1○360÷⍨○d←2÷⍨⍳360
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97X@KjoGCGQg96pjxqGvJoRWPerr0TLUftU1M1jm0wujwdAOdR70rDq030tVPftQ2wcTYKNX48HTDR9O7jc0MDm8HygGZKUAZIwindzNQHGT0/zQA)

`d←2÷⍨⍳360` all the angles \$\theta\$ from 0.5 to 180.
`1○` Sine of `360÷⍨○` \$\theta \over 2\$ in radians.
`432e3×` Multiply by \$432000 = 60×60×120\$. This gives the chord length adjusted such that both sexagesimal digits are in the integer part.

`¯2-/` Differences of adjacent values, for the "sixtieths" column.
`0,⍨` Append a 0, this hardcodes the sixtieths for 180°.
`2×` Multiply each value by \$2 = 60 ÷ 30\$.

`↑c,¨` Pair up each chord length with corresponding sixtieths value. This results in a matrix with two columns.
`⌊.5+` Round all values to the nearest integer.
`0 60 60∘⊤¨` Convert each value from "base 60", where the first of three digit is unbounded.

`d,` prepend the angles on the left of the table.

Comment: While it's not required, it's generally appreciated if you present a decomposition and explanation, much like the answers in Vyxal and 05AB1E.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Added some text, this is a very literal implementation of the challenge specification, just with some of the constants combined.

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97X@KjoGCGQg96pjxqGvJoRWPerr0TLU1HvWu0jF41NNhdHi6IUiqZ6/uo65FmibGRqnGIKHp3RpAfHj7o85FmimP2iYYAZm9Kx71bjY2MwCZ/D8NAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>204 210 202 191 208 206 194 190 188 180 166</s> 147 bytes

```python
from math import*;j=0
while j<360:C=pi/720;j+=1;p=sin(C*j);print(j/2,*[[(x:=round(432e3*y))//3600,x//60%60,x%60]for y in[p,max(sin(C*-~j)-p,0)*2]])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc49DoIwAAXg3VN0MWlrSWsxaKidOAZhIBFCG_qTWiIsXsLRhUXv5G0kQZeXt7yX7_n2U-ycnefXENvk9Hm0wRlg6tgBZbwLEQst2ebWqb4B-pxmLC-kV_TImdA7uRdeXpWFBdZI-KBshJpygssSjrkMbrAXeEh5k-IJIUqXOSMjpRnbZktZompdABNQtvTE1CNcz5K7RoknDGFeVWil_YR_6Rc)
or [see it in a nicer format](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY69DoIwAIR3n6KLsa0lrWDQgJ18DGTACKGN_UkpsSy-hKOLi76TbyMRlrsvudzlnh87-Nbo13djrBPa878uJr5W6nypcMimDOJAutryFTh5sELv3jfR_vtonFFAVb4FQlnjPM4lZ4tbK641kIckZdmRW0F3Mcvlmm9yyzuh4RFLlE-zksYEFwUMGXem1xe4TeI6wQNClI51RgKlKVumI4xSNsaBAQhdWKKqAKex6C5RZAlDOC7L-dprttl_).

Thanks to *@Neil* for pointing out a bug and saving <s>2 14</s> 16 bytes. 
Thanks to *@pan* for saving 8 bytes. 
Thanks to *@xnor* for saving <s>14</s> 33 bytes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `60.0` should be `[60, 0, 0]`, not `[59, 59, 60]`.

Comment: Actually that was just one example; there are still five other cases.

Comment: @Neil I've rewritten the `f` function to only handle integers. Does this look fine now?

Comment: I think you can write `g=lambda x:120*sin(radians(x/2))*a` and then the last line can be golfed to end `print(j,f(round(g(j))),f(round(max(g(j+.5)-g(j),0)*2)))`.

Comment: @Neil thanks, updated.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear last time but `f((k:=round((g(j+.5)-g(j))*2))>0and k or 0)` can be `f(round(max(g(j+.5)-g(j),0)*2))` as well.

Comment: @Neil oh yes, thanks

Comment: `j=0` and `while j<180:j+=.5;` saves another two bytes.

Comment: [180](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU9JDoIwALz7ih7bsrRgJITalxgPNQi0oYVgiYWveOGiL_Az_kZwvc2Wyczl1g62asw0XXtbBOnjXnSNBlrYCkjdNp3FTPB1QikreC30IRfAZbsh444Q4Y8Zhy4YsECEJNR_wWDECd2z8h-PYopP0sBWkrkJO4QFU5yuzpWsj0Bto5RmyuPhhrWdNBYqv4Bd05scllAhhH5UC7dIXrhBwWL5FOF4Dry3fy58rzwB) bytes by omitting some parentheses and replacing `radians(x/2)` with `pi/360*x`.

Comment: @pan thanks, updated

Comment: It looks like you can [simplify `f` quite a bit using `%`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5LDoIwFEXnroIJSVuBFgyEULsS4-AZBNpQSrDEuhYnTGRP7kaIv9HN_SXnPvc325humh6jrcL8OVeD0Z4G23hS92awhIPYZYzxSrSgTyV4rjg4SiFwPlCasVX9jB15_R_ECSMX2aFe0uVLHCbAlWCbayPbs6f2cc4KtRVRyvtBdhapoEKDGbsS1UhhjH9Wg1ujbZTicK0ChkmyDN60H-gv_As).

Comment: @xnor thanks, updated

Comment: [147 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc49DoIwAAXgnVN0MWlrSWsx1YCdOAZhIBFCG_uTWiIsXsLRhUXv5G0kQZeXt7yX7_n2U-ydnefXELv0-Hl0wRlgmtgDZbwLESdasuTWq0sL9CkTLC-lV_TAWaG3cld4eVUWllijwgdlI9SUE1xVcMxlcIM9w33G2wxPCFG6zBkZKRVsI5ayRN25ACagbOWJaUa4nqV3jVJPGMK8rtFK-wn_0i8)

Comment: @xnor no way, I didn't think it could be golfed even more!

Comment: @xnor Heh, your previous version calculated `x%3600%60`, fortunately your 147-byte version simplifies that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```
≔⁶⁰θ⊞υ²⮌Ｅ³⁶⁰⪫⁺⟦∕⁻³⁶⁰κ²⟧Ｅ⁺·⁵×Ｘθ³⁺υ⊗⁻⊟υ⊞Ｏυ↔⊕ＸＩ1j∕ι¹⁸⁰⟦÷⌊λ×θθ﹪÷⌊λθθ﹪⌊λθ⟧
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDPSsQwEMbx6lOEnKaQla6LsrCnxUVYoVjEW-khbaMbzWba_KkP42UPij6TT2PSjeLBQCDD9_u-mcnrZ7vjpkWuDod37x5my6-TYm2tfNRwmTMyZKvT0tsdeEbO49tI7eBOjMJYAQXvYRGxG5QaSuUtVBs5yi5IUodqEp-z6K0ZifgE5WcXjNzLvbBQ4oswMDCyCNQkhk4b9I0SXQopsQcf1TDHbS8Md2gitW4sKu8EbHVrxF5oFyzHvCtuHdD5Ew22NJBkZL7Ms9_DSLXVLonXCkOmyn6mGuLmoSqw8wrhP3BINyF_hTpaKaGxzerNNq1Nf_tR0dmoaJ3Kbw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁶⁰θ
```

Assign \$60\$ to a variable because it gets used enough times to make it worthwhile.

```
⊞υ²
```

Set the "next" chord to \$2\$, so that the linear interpolation values for \$180°\$ become zero.

```
⮌Ｅ³⁶⁰⪫⁺
```

Map downwards from \$180°\$ to \$0.5°\$, with the final output reversed, joining together...

```
⟦∕⁻³⁶⁰κ²⟧
```

... the angle, and, ...

```
Ｅ⁺·⁵×Ｘθ³⁺υ⊗⁻⊟υ⊞Ｏυ↔⊕ＸＩ1j∕ι¹⁸⁰
```

...mapping over the current chord and the difference between the previous and the current chord, ...

```
⟦÷⌊λ×θθ﹪÷⌊λθθ﹪⌊λθ⟧
```

... convert to sexagesimal.

Chords are calculated by using the identity \$2|\sin(45x°)|=|i^{2-x}+1|\$ . Note that the although the variable containing the current chord is referenced before the actual calculation, it's actually a list and gets mutated to the correct value before it is mapped over.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 38 bytes

```
kRɾ½:½∆R∆s»⟇₀¨»*:¯d0JZƛƛṙ2(60ḋ÷$)^W;;Z
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQ4biLVCIsIiIsImtSyb7CvTrCveKIhlLiiIZzwrvin4figoDCqMK7KjrCr2QwSlrGm8ab4bmZMig2MOG4i8O3JCleVzs7WiIsIiIsIiJd)

Outputs as a list of `[a,[[b,c,d],[d,e,f]]]`. The online interpreter times out after about outputting about half of the table.

First get the lengths a list of angles and the lengths of chord of the unit circle.

```
kR         # push 360
  ɾ        # inclusive 1 range
   ½       # halve
    :      # duplicate
     ½     # halve
      ∆R   # convert to radians
        ∆s # sine
```

Get the numbers in the second and third column multiplied by 3600.

```
»⟇₀¨»        # push 60*60*120
     *       # multiply
      :      # duplicate
       ¯     # consecutive differences
        d    # double
         0J  # append 0
           Z # zip
```

Convert to base sixty and zip with angles

```
ƛƛ               # map map:
  ṙ              #   round
   2(            #   for n in range(2):
     60ḋ         #     div mod by 60
        ÷        #     push each to stack
         $       #     swap
          )      #   end for
           ^W    #   reverse stack and wrap it in a list
             ;;  # end map end map
               Z # zip
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
360©L;Džq*®/Å½•6¥U•*D¥0ª·øòεε2F60‰`s})R]‚ø
```

-19 bytes porting the approaches used in [*@AndrovT*'s Vyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257749/52210) and [*@ovs*' APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257750/52210) answers, which is also much faster, so make sure to upvote both of them as well!

Outputs as a list of `[a,[[b,c,d],[e,f,g]]]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9vc2FiaWX//zM2MMKpTDtExb5xKsKuL8OFwr3igKI2wqVV4oCiKkTCpTDCqsK3w7jDss61zrUyRjYw4oCwYHN9KVJd4oCaw7j//w) or [verify everything is correct](https://tio.run/##XZrLyqdHEcZvZTIrE15iV3dXH8wiCJOAIAGDASEMJMZZDASjSTxkEZiNN@FSCHgAESGYhUb4Rre5iNzI2FX1PPWfEQZmvvf3Pe@h@@mq6ur56JP3f/r40bNnbZS7P/3wtQf//fqXr9z99btPf3f3r2@f/GHcffHO@euVB3dflLs/3/3j6VdP//7Nl998Wd8c5dsnf3vvk89ffvvht09@//SrZ@/8@v6j3/7i0QefPvrZ9@7df/2z1@@/du/9Dz791fsf2o8/eevpHx@8/tl753fPnx89vn/vOx989PHH59dfvv/0L@enBz9488033n7jrR@/9PL9u39@fn1@9/V/njy@@/r@03/f@82jjx/de/xzCF4ywfc//PAefr7/@fXs3XfLq3q9W64mV9WH17vnr0vLQ/vXqyV/fPG62o@tX0JB3waqCc5vXW3/33W1621e/YXrzX6/Xeuqi9dXXFe73val7QXQTXAeK5dMghlADfTzc3kBqCn0kn579Ijrate7XjXvpAaGCcYlw94RoAdQA32dxxM0A9MU85J9tXzbGkANaLk0Hy4GlinOV9fnBrAEUAN6vp2g@UhtU@yr9tut2gqgBvS8MR/e/AOl@OyV831naokUSB3pun1k82@RmPMzuYeSVBATnVe@at4u7ODTLvaL9uxAdQGZ6HzOzUPV50V87o1ozkxVENP0yyaBJF7Op/@QY6R0TBUgE@nxUiMRHzlxB4h50iwBNIFMdJ5zPpaPEp9scRuYCc43kVQQE535bhfHTmIc3AiH9G53CTRBTHOcozfjxse6FQ7p46o5QiCm2UdwG/B4jpvhkGNFELl0AtlKK2ZG2UT@RdX9cNCxI8b1IAEylU2sfWSgWHDV/XCua70oinVS3Q/HwuePLiJ/9RpxoJqPO98ifFwjFDRzckvkhq3uiIM016TAldUtcSQ1bX5eNm7onrB1MW6vUQeQqexutu6A4g3dFAeprUKg8Et1U5wH1TOEJPHF7olDdN/eXQTIRNOWDZa0XDGAboq6rmIjilECUAcWdwuIz291T9jjuWjcnkHUyVlpsojii9wU5/EeroJgCt0Th7QTaUn8FZpb4jy/2UoOEtPU3BFGcgYLgkdzR5wX6NckEAB1cPICxrRgJpobwu7FuFYwEc39cMgR9QEUq7NFdjjXjyNIKog6ObFDQCJvuBnOVb2oaLiufv38sYcUm0INiTuhDUiCNBB1gqc4Qn5yJ1g6i1cL1IDUkb34JItY3dwLbdkw5GtEdG3uhoM4eM4iVDb3g4Wv2yti9NwPbfs05R0lxtwN0c8IRFoPJEAaqF0lP9rTqDuiIx@AFBB10iIgevKIyNLdEd0yQytEyNfuCYuhyIHB/OW7m6K3C0vGUZtA6qjufI8Fm/UGGZOXs0gd3Y1xwu9ZVkIk8SZROpwhnBauySqYydTDyyDzUexuj4NOUJJ8WgEy1bBQRjThne4GOexEQN5xslRxh/RpgTNlURd0N8hBKpwYMxKQqZZFdvpqwiDdDdJt0HMGJhJjd4t0TyMiZJHkelhkWxV0u@cEsvqoWOFUU@bfre6Rg860KtDAd6u7RMUrtEWGisttouKJOHURb9R9cnLM4ncPLAx1l6hVFjmSA9OtbhNLMpYMgCJ4qLvE6igrO5MVMJN1i4Mtn@bETaLunw672tSDhco@qJKFzTWqTPWspskKmDrTmgtR@XFuE/ueEonXGT7ObWIPm7l0lF/nPrF51Fwfem0gdXRWyEyVE3eJmb5EjWRLkvPmLrE1tq5OFHle3SQWICIrO4plqmEST0cMPx15ebhLRjmDXJIIiDqpt5XYsRKHQGVX8mkdyGRRpGC2G/LicJMM8eJ8kMVyG26SUb32KmRhu@EuGVaWn0CXrICZznYntELjF7hNhteunNJmhUkwk3WrCvNFHLhHhnuLc1bhraEQaaYa7lNG7EfUPrt2shj/EVsSW7zpZFbewy0yrF6y2hAsSpzhHjnspICRKL7aTTKmFd/5JgKiTlpNrwqKj7GhOg6aRJ3IZCdCtxxilnUzPGJx3MwGVslMt23aat4z4tYMl1gYoVtRVE03yTyflRm2YIyne@SgWwIrsPisUFnUTFmUO9MtMq1wzDFmWTPdIofZEk1dpN/pHpnVxr8TkaiTxsHqGz6e7pHp2yWSTqJO6owy11kUznNApbkMD6tkpuu@i9hkUc/O2Lj6rjllJKbSa0Sha6Ukh9ENctApDgdRJwqVxbCURfqa7pA5PH2lrpKpM0/qZLGclltkzotxye4IoA5avvyEG5dAY4GVCBvv8IdnUU0WhcUKgyx7DcRHS9IFzHT7mgxLB/laWuGP7RUO7jhQW64GlWYS7QNhabk/lhW7jC99YEKXO@QwK8SIIissd8g6lmPRdFCsiuUWOahOlpAdeW0NqMy6YWIraSqYydyoiKuduWu5Q5Yn30QR39eELMpAsKi1VvQ3LFxaogMbQOqos5jtHc5abpFl@37Ex4OiqF7ukOWxkw/ryKG7QGbhoZDFtG03yVL7tpos@iZukuVbAsTVznSyBTK9jWSDybe7ZLmROQMN8Wy7Sw478yZEkTK222TN6A0BbRAN0pm7rLByk@wOlc2IkuFFwiQnhjCKsIezwyPWVctPY59kK1QWPZLFi4RJttcHmG3hiIRJtq16lFMWe913e0JnuSd1mBx3yS5uLiWLLLTdJdt3IZpsAoXMS7FAjOM7WmGWC1JWkGx2dMPEt2yDDF2qUiC08ksI0Qkq7pTtVUIveddgbpVdvVUVk9c2Vo/BENpdF2GUF1LcLLs9l8QaI7NBddiyMDkwwp6UBqXmNrJhJ2bMhNZkYjSysg0f4pY50LaEQsi@X4dSKyNtW@ygFbfNPi/Dfclhi0gdnemXWJtnh6u46YDOcp8Q9kpoyhM@EMnaRACR4r45yNozg1AGYeh8f0WIsQnjPLf7bgMNZWPqrOaKbyM7optCybka2EobDKVt5Tdh3DV6qXtZsEb8sSbDIFSHdkkI8f3RT93e0kX50BhCJVqq27blaQ9Fcpboqh549sD5SCEKncV3jEDHVkTQWC228UfBZZ2STqgBrYoepBEtBf3VEq5IOgghvaV3W7loG0eXtVgDkTVxY5ktaLQW8aZaJ0W/F73WIp6UJqkIqWtrdKIdMj4KWq6lejgm7I0QShvylHLwF6UqLBZbzdGP7ms5myim58b2K/qvh9WWUFCoSbRgjVocmKRootdCrY1iI5VF6lo/4ah542DRmS/eBEXoboW@j26sUYvZixTrPhqyRnXmtBdOe/RkzyL3uUsan1NhJ@@iYtprRr/aKO057XVjeyK1U2uPbaRo5lcYynYaXMiHYiTgp3F5JzbgotuqUhppARRuq4NaVWadymJTKvw0r81FdyCUsJOHD5itZqCrk8p2G4qJUknqolZzg2pDpqSuXbaNJsOxQYWfrFVFx1iXeZBCabYnjHJWWqG051bUBmyQ8qGLAa8OLqwGQ3n4QWyqGdUaDOVnTkgkh/K5lVqLypWUz63Uavb2DuVzw1F2MhX97eLHWoNQA4qygxQv4LSndOYH9Tw36tRaehZSjHI0eo2qcLfmhw2krrVeuDZCTG20ew1adZCUjx2U1tw@VhR3Ei1fv@9GI8TORTohlFaXT1LYONq@4iduPSEWT3R@HWYqPzQWT7R@DdrgBBOunWj@GjyhHQmiCpdsNICN3nqClacmEk1go7a1WqQxdR1HhxYyMfgFB0wSfWBjchujDE/RCTZaM9rWDE/RDDbaMvtW1ma9UXrbgwvb9NIbpdaZLaQ46uxwUz8v3FKKgrDDTL5zhoc9xzhUKutg7eJneKSQ5rZJFqvQPijtufGwg8FOCqk12WIUreYIR3SYSXlgE7vHRqgBbd4rKU5b@6LUnECIFdkXpTVbszK4NPrOp65rEWJp9E1pT0fIYKzVQqmVsYV0Ebp08MjK1zwSi8JMfjZLpbKQU6FUVj5VaRit1NZxJexkULaW983aSRuV2VkS7jNFG6XWuUgpClbtlFpiX6SF0KUzDsadNWyfRGEmT0iFEOfnqlTacwlxEq2DylrzYypDqY586OYw8P8ZiE5KW25NPF6QQtqFe0HhWbYuSm9tR@FRsuiiNLqsoFjpuqnVzTggkif1MJMlyWTh7gEnRfca71u46RmFwjNKhRArbgilVXIllzznF0rr4LLh2aCMSmkTdnA2S/tRqbSjCSqRFEaj8lahbOSE0SjsWUlnaTN6CjcDGo/FZPQcoM46etH2Q6nU3Pcv2H7ARvvKCm/S9AMu2teg/9gSkzGoE7aKJ0vkMamT3NsMhqoxUzg5OCNHblFpOYBKFA9j5avmoSZPbmTsVI48fMqh26nccdhuEEM3C5X8XyoGMXSzUHlrHDBiTEnh5F0zYEyhsOcJTufgzUplz2XfOXqzpjLPjBp9N1sqb7U@R2@2VK7canH0ZqdSCxY9S5HZqdNbvcexm5q6hpyV/5FopnmsHYOaIIcu3aOaxSsW7Uz3aDaShWt2pn00S0jhmp1pHzuvwnLnkp1pn1vvseTQpX10c4NVWD/OtI9t8qnEkp37OSVWHv5fgUQb@uzP8jjL/n748H8).

**Original <s>62</s> 61 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
360©>L;ü2εžq*®/Å½ƵJ*Ć`-30/‚T.òεU59ÝNÌãXïδšΣ®ćÝm/OXα}нNi¦}}yнš
```

Outputs as a list of `[a,[b,c,d],[e,f,g]]`.

Extremely slow.. It's barely fast enough to output the first result.

[(Don't) try it online.](https://tio.run/##AWMAnP9vc2FiaWX//zM2MMKpPkw7w7wyzrXFvnEqwq4vw4XCvca1SirEhmAtMzAv4oCaVC7Dss61VTU5w51Ow4zDo1jDr860xaHOo8KuxIfDnW0vT1jOsX3QvU5pwqZ9fXnQvcWh//8)

Instead:

- [Verify all the first four values with a speed up variant.](https://tio.run/##XZrNqqdHEcZv5WRWJrwmXd1d/aGLIEwCulCUCMKQRYyzCIREk/iRRSCbeAEuBReSlQgGBXcmwhzjMuQaciNjV9Xz1D8RBmbO@5vn/eh@uqq6@rz97ms/f@PxU933f7r/@Ke/ef/LTx@@@ODuq9//4e7x7375@PX3Hv/iO3cPXnz//qN3X3zw3bvXXn/v16@9aVeefv7Zr55ro7xw/9GTT//7zx8898rz9/948pf7T372xcejPHzrqw//@MKPnvzt4f0n3/7i7x98@em7n//56UO/z4/feHD3rdfffuedc/dnH9z/9fz08Psvv/zST1764SvPPPvgyb8@uD548tl/PnzjyWcP7v9999vH7zy@e@MtCJ4xwffefPMOPz/44Hr66FF5Xq9H5WpyVX31enT@urS8av96vuSP37yu9mPrl1DQt4FqgvO/rrb/77ra9Tav/o3rzf5/u9ZVF6@vuK52ve1L2zdAN8F5rFwyCWYANdDPz@UbQE2hl/Tbo0dcV7ve9ap5JzUwTDAuGfaOAD2AGujrPJ6gGZimmJfsq@Xb1gBqQMul@XAxsExxvrp@bQBLADWg59sJmo/UNsW@ar/dqq0AakDPG/PhzT9Qis9eOd93ppZIgdSRrttHNv8WiTk/k3soSQUx0Xnlq@btwg4@7WL/0Z4dqC4gE53PuXmo@ryIz70RzZmpCmKaftkkkMTL@fQfcoyUjqkCZCI9Xmok4iMn7gAxT5olgCaQic5zzsfyUeKTLW4DM8H5JpIKYqIz3@3i2EmMgxvhkN7tLoEmiGmOc/Rm3PhYt8IhfVw1RwjENPsIbgMez3EzHHKsCCKXTiBbacXMKJvIv6i6Hw46dsS4HiRAprKJtY8MFAuuuh/Oda0XRbFOqvvhWPj80UXkr14jDlTzcedbhI9rhIJmTm6J3LDVHXGQ5poUuLK6JY6kps3Py8YN3RO2LsbtNeoAMpXdzdYdULyhm@IgtVUIFH6pborzoHqGkCS@2D1xiO7bu4sAmWjassGSlisG0E1R11VsRDFKAOrA4m4B8fmt7gl7PBeN2zOIOjkrTRZRfJGb4jzew1UQTKF74pB2Ii2Jv0JzS5znN1vJQWKamjvCSM5gQfBo7ojzAv2aBAKgDk5ewJgWzERzQ9i9GNcKJqK5Hw45oj6AYnW2yA7n@nEESQVRJyd2CEjkDTfDuaoXFQ3X1a@fP/aQYlOoIXEntAFJkAaiTvAUR8hP7gRLZ/FqgRqQOrIXn2QRq5t7oS0bhnyNiK7N3XAQB89ZhMrmfrDwdXtFjJ77oW2fpryjxJi7IfoZgUjrgQRIA7Wr5Ed7GnVHdOQDkAKiTloERE8eEVm6O6JbZmiFCPnaPWExFDkwmL98d1P0dmHJOGoTSB3Vne@xYLPeIGPychapo7sxTvg9y0qIJN4kSoczhNPCNVkFM5l6eBlkPord7XHQCUqSTytAphoWyogmvNPdIIedCMg7TpYq7pA@LXCmLOqC7gY5SIUTY0YCMtWyyE5fTRiku0G6DXrOwERi7G6R7mlEhCySXA@LbKuCbvecQFYfFSucasr8u9U9ctCZVgUa@G51l6h4hbbIUHG5TVQ8Eacu4o26T06OWfzugYWh7hK1yiJHcmC61W1iScaSAVAED3WXWB1lZWeyAmaybnGw5dOcuEnU/dNhV5t6sFDZB1WysLlGlame1TRZAVNnWnMhKj/ObWLfUyLxOsPHuU3sYTOXjvLr3Cc2j5rrQ68NpI7OCpmpcuIuMdOXqJFsSXLe3CW2xtbViSLPq5vEAkRkZUexTDVM4umI4acjLw93yShnkEsSAVEn9bYSO1biEKjsSj6tA5ksihTMdkNeHG6SIV6cD7JYbsNNMqrXXoUsbDfcJcPK8hPokhUw09nuhFZo/AK3yfDalVParDAJZrJuVWG@iAP3yHBvcc4qvDUUIs1Uw33KiP2I2mfXThbjP2JLYos3nczKe7hFhtVLVhuCRYkz3COHnRQwEsVXu0nGtOI730RA1Emr6VVB8TE2VMdBk6gTmexE6JZDzLJuhkcsjpvZwCqZ6bZNW817Rtya4RILI3QriqrpJpnnszLDFozxdI8cdEtgBRafFSqLmimLcme6RaYVjjnGLGumW@QwW6Kpi/Q73SOz2vh3IhJ10jhYfcPH0z0yfbtE0knUSZ1R5jqLwnkOqDSX4WGVzHTddxGbLOrZGRtX3zWnjMRUeo0odK2U5DC6QQ46xeEg6kShshiWskhf0x0yh6ev1FUydeZJnSyW03KLzHkxLtkdAdRBy5efcOMSaCywEmHjHf7wLKrJorBYYZBlr4H4aEm6gJluX5Nh6SBfSyv8sb3CwR0HasvVoNJMon0gLC33x7Jil/GlD0zococcZoUYUWSF5Q5Zx3Ismg6KVbHcIgfVyRKyI6@tAZVZN0xsJU0FM5kbFXG1M3ctd8jy5Jso4vuakEUZCBa11or@hoVLS3RgA0gddRazvcNZyy2ybN@P@HhQFNXLHbI8dvJhHTl0F8gsPBSymLbtJllq31aTRd/ETbJ8S4C42plOtkCmt5FsMPl2lyw3MmegIZ5td8lhZ96EKFLGdpusGb0hoA2iQTpzlxVWbpLdobIZUTK8SJjkxBBGEfZwdnjEumr5aeyTbIXKokeyeJEwyfb6ALMtHJEwybZVj3LKYq/7bk/oLPekDpPjLtnFzaVkkYW2u2T7LkSTTaCQeSkWiHF8RyvMckHKCpLNjm6Y@JZtkKFLVQqEVn4JITpBxZ2yvUroJe8azK2yq7eqYvLaxuoxGEK76yKM8kKKm2W3ryWxxshsUB22LEwOjLAnpUGpuY1s2IkZM6E1mRiNrGzDh7hlDrQtoRCy79eh1MpI2xY7aMVts8/LcF9y2CJSR2f6Jdbm2eEqbjqgs9wnhL0SmvKED0SyNhFApLhvDrL2zCCUQRg6318RYmzCOF/bfbeBhrIxdVZzxbeRHdFNoeRcDWylDYbStvKbMO4avdS9LFgj/liTYRCqQ7skhPj@6Kdub@mifGgMoRIt1W3b8rSHIjlLdFUPPHvgfKQQhc7iO0agYysiaKwW2/ij4LJOSSfUgFZFD9KIloL@aglXJB2EkN7Su61ctI2jy1qsgciauLHMFjRai3hTrZOi34teaxFPSpNUhNS1NTrRDhkfBS3XUj0cE/ZGCKUNeUo5@ItSFRaLreboR/e1nE0U03Nj@xX918NqSygo1CRasEYtDkxSNNFrodZGsZHKInWtn3DUvHGw6MwXb4IidLdC30c31qjF7EWKdR8NWaM6c9oLpz16smeR@9wljc@psJN3UTHtNaNfbZT2nPa6sT2R2qm1xzZSNPMrDGU7DS7kQzES8NO4vBMbcNFtVSmNtAAKt9VBrSqzTmWxKRV@mtfmojsQStjJwwfMVjPQ1Ulluw3FRKkkdVGruUG1IVNS1y7bRpPh2KDCT9aqomOsyzxIoTTbE0Y5K61Q2nMragM2SPnQxYBXBxdWg6E8/CA21YxqDYbyMyckkkP53EqtReVKyudWajV7e4fyueEoO5mK/nbxY61BqAFF2UGKF3DaUzrzg3qeG3VqLT0LKUY5Gr1GVbhb88MGUtdaL1wbIaY22r0GrTpIyscOSmtuHyuKO4mWr993oxFi5yKdEEqryycpbBxtX/ETt54Qiyc6vw4zlR8aiydavwZtcIIJ1040fw2e0I4EUYVLNhrARm89wcpTE4kmsFHbWi3SmLqOo0MLmRj8ggMmiT6wMbmNUYan6AQbrRlta4anaAYbbZl9K2uz3ii97cGFbXrpjVLrzBZSHHV2uKmfF24pRUHYYSbfOcPDnmMcKpV1sHbxMzxSSHPbJItVaB@U9tx42MFgJ4XUmmwxilZzhCM6zKQ8sIndYyPUgDbvlRSnrX1Rak4gxIrsi9KarVkZXBp951PXtQixNPqmtKcjZDDWaqHUythCughdOnhk5WseiUVhJj@bpVJZyKlQKiufqjSMVmrruBJ2Mihby/tm7aSNyuwsCfeZoo1S61ykFAWrdkotsS/SQujSGQfjzhq2T6IwkyekQojzc1Uq7bmEOInWQWWt@TGVoVRHPnRzGPh7BqKT0pZbE48XpJB24V5QeJati9Jb21F4lCy6KI0uKyhWum5qdTMOiORJPcxkSTJZuHvASdG9xvsWbnpGofCMUiHEihtCaZVcySXP@YXSOrhseDYoo1LahB2czdJ@VCrtaIJKJIXRqLxVKBs5YTQKe1bSWdqMnsLNgMZjMRk9B6izjl60/VAqNff9C7YfsNG@ssKbNP2Ai/Y16D@2xGQM6oSt4skSeUzqJPc2g6FqzBRODs7IkVtUWg6gEsXDWPmqeajJkxsZO5UjD59y6HYqdxy2G8TQzUIlf0vFIIZuFipvjQNGjCkpnLxrBowpFPY8wekcvFmp7LnsO0dv1lTmmVGj72ZL5a3W5@jNlsqVWy2O3uxUasGiZykyO3V6q/c4dlNT15Cz8heJZprH2jGoCXLo0j2qWbxi0c50j2YjWbhmZ9pHs4QUrtmZ9rHzKix3LtmZ9rn1HksOXdpHNzdYhfXjTPvYJp9KLNm5v6bEysPvFUi0oc/@LI@z7O9XX/0f)
- [Try it online with a given input.](https://tio.run/##AV8AoP9vc2FiaWX//y41K@KAmsW@cSozNjDCqS/DhcK9xrVKKsSGYC0zMC/igJpULsOyzrVVNTnDnU7DjMOjWMOvzrTFoc6jwq7Eh8OdbS9PWM6xfdC9TmnCpl1JxaH//zExMg)

#### Explanation:

```python
360              # Push 360
   ©             # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    L            # Pop and push a list in the range [1,360]
     ;           # Halve each to [0.5,180.0] in 0.5 increments
D                # Duplicate this [0.5,180.0]-list
 žq*             # Multiply each by PI (3.141592653589793)
    ®/           # Divide each by the 360 from variable `®`
      Å½         # Take the sine of each
        •6¥U•*   # Multiply each by compressed 432000 (60*60*120)
D                # Duplicate this list
 ¥               # Get the deltas / forward-differences of this copy
  0ª             # Append a 0
    ·            # Double each
     ø           # Zip it with the duplicated list to create pairs
ò                # Round each decimal value to the nearest integer
 ε               # Map over each pair:
  ε              #  Map over both integers in this pair:
   2F            #   Loop 2 times:
     60‰         #    Divmod the integer at the top of the stack by 60
        `        #    Pop and push y//60 and y%60 separated to the stack
         s       #    Swap so the y//60 is at the top of the stack
    }            #   After the inner loop:
     )           #   Wrap the three values on the stack into a list
      R          #   Reverse it
 ]               # Close the nested maps
  ‚ø             # Pair and zip it with the duplicated [0.5,180.0]-list
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
360              # Push 360
   ©             # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    >            # Increase it by 1: 361
     L           # Pop and push a list in the range [1,361]
      ;          # Halve each to [0.5,180.5] in 0.5 increments
       ü2        # Get it's overlapping pairs: [[0.5,1.0],[1.0,1.5],...,[180.0,180.5]]
ε                # Map over each pair `y`:
 žq*             #  Multiply each by PI (3.141592653589793)
    ®/           #  Divide each by the 360 from variable `®`
      Å½         #  Take the sine of each
        ƵJ*      #  Multiply each by a compressed 120
 Ć               #  Enclose; append its own head
  `              #  Pop and push all three values to the stack
   -             #  Subtract the top two
    30/          #  Divide it by 30
       ‚         #  Pair it back together with the third value
        T.ò      #  Round each to 10 decimals (work-around for 59.999... → 60)
 ε               #  Inner map over this pair:
  U              #   Pop and store the current value in variable `X`
  59Ý            #   Push a list in the range [0,59]
     NÌ          #   Push the 0-based index + 2 (1st iteration = 2; 2nd iteration = 3)
       ã         #   Get the cartesian power to create all possible pairs/triplets
        Xï       #   Push value `X` and floor it to an integer
          δ      #   Map over each pair/triplet with this integer as argument
           š     #    Prepend it in front of each pair/triplet
  Σ              #   Sort this list of triplets/quadruplets by:
   ®             #    Push 360 from variable `®`
    ć            #    Head extracted; push 60 and 3 separated to the stack
     Ý           #    Pop and push a list in the range [0,3]
      m          #    Take 60 to the power each: [1,60,360,216000]
       /         #    Divide the values in the triplet/quadruplet by this
                 #    (the 216000 is ignored when dividing the triplet)
        O        #    Sum them together
         Xα      #    Get the absolute difference with value `X`
  }н             #   After the sort-by: pop and leave the first/closest
    Ni }         #   If the 0-based map-index is 1 (second iteration):
      ¦          #    Remove the leading 0
}                #  Close the outer map
 yн              #  Push the first item of pair `y`
   š             #  Prepend it to the pair of triplets
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•6¥U•` is `432000` and `ƵJ` is `120` (and why `360` isn't shorter when compressed).

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 141 bytes

```
{($_».polymod(60,60)Z(((.[1..*]Z-$_)Xmax
0)X*2)».polymod(60 xx 3)).map:{++$
/2,|$_».round»[2...0]}}([(1..361).map((*/720*π).sin*432e3)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcwxCoMwFADQ3VNkcPg/2m9MJIWeRJQgghYKaiRSUKzQe7l5gR4pLW7dH29sXac9TfXC7tb5FcLq2Gm03dLbBrSItcACAKhMibgpLmGFeV/PgcCcS/yzbJ6ZQqS@Hm9rFIVBIuPX@Tn7HJpjLyURCbNtUMKvUzo9MQBPrlLwzxtpegw8U7JVaND7Lw)

- The initial sine values are generated by `(1..361).map((* / 720 * π).sin * 432e3)`.  The values are scaled up by an additional factor of 3,600 so that they can be fed to the `polymod` methods later.
- `$_».polymod(60, 60)` generates columns 2-4.
- `.[1..*] Z- $_` zips the tail of the list with the full list using subtraction.
- `Xmax 0` makes each number zero if it's negative.
- `X* 2` doubles each number.  2 here is the multiplicative factor of 60 for feeding to `polymod`, divided by the 30 from the interpolation formula.
- `».polymod(60 xx 3)` generates columns 5-7.
- The `map` generates the final list.  `++$ / 2` is the first column, increasing by one half each iteration, and the two `polymod` list results are `rounded` and shown in order of the indices 2, 1, 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 163 bytes

```perl
sub h{120*sin+(pop//$_)/229.183118}$d=' [%d, %d, %d]';printf"%.1f$d$d\n",$_/2,map{$x=1/7200+$_,60*($x-int$x),$x<0?0:60*($x*60-int$x*60)}(h,(h($_+1)-h)*2)for 1..360
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrrCoIwGEBfZcgnbnPuJpldpAepGMWSCaVDCwbisy/BHwcOh@Nf43sX4/R7IjcrLenU9Tn2gxcCDBFaH7iqS6XqBWyToWtqGdq4Zyc/dv23TVKuWrBgb33CwAjNPg8/Q2iU2GspczCskhRDKNYbAmEQzvIij1ukldz6KmTBjmGHweSKFI5QTdphRIrzspIx/gE)